# Mysql not displaying any results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i have a users username in side $_GET ['nicky']  so i escape it then try and use it to grab all info about that user in the db but its now showing any results.

If i echo out the get it will show the username but if i echo out the sql i get Resource id #3

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$_SESSION ['nicky'] = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET ['nicky'] ) ;


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE username='". $_SESSION ['nicky']."'") or die(mysql_error());  
// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );


?>
</p>
<center>
  <h2 align="left"><?php echo  $row ['username'] ;?> Profile</h2>
```

I have checked the db and there is a column called username in side the table user.
The config.php stores the sql connect and the session start which is being used all over the site and works fine

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($row); exit;` to see what you get?

Comment: Yep it shows nothing ...

Comment: Then you need to check your query. `exit("SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE username='". $_SESSION ['nicky']."'");` and then inspect it, and if there doesn't seem to a problem, run the query directly on your myself (for instance, use phpMyAdmin).

Comment: can you print your qurey before you fetch array? and make sure it is correct, then try it in your mysql shell.

Comment: So I'm guessing it doesn't die with a mysql_error? Try doing a var_dump() of $result and see what it says.

Comment: Also, this looks possibly problematic: *in side the table user*. Is it `user` or `users` (the last indicated in the query)?

Comment: its users and the page don't die ....

Comment: From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php): *mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error* and *mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.* Your "error checking" is insufficient to debug your problem, which is probably that the query is syntactically correct but has no results. As I said, check the *actual generated query* directly in MySQL (shell or phpMyAdmin). Or, try `SELECT 1 + 1` and see if you get a result.

Comment: Also: *Use [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.*

Answer (score 1):

Remove the use of $_SESSION. May be you are not initialized it or something else. Just put escaped username into the SQL

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET ['nicky'] ) ;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
   WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you want requested username to be stored in session (hightly possible you dont, but if you still want), make sure you initialized session: called session_start() in config.php

Comment: that still didnt work...... i have $username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET ['nicky'] ) ;

$result123 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
   WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());


// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result123 );


?>
</p>
<center>
  <h2 align="left"><?php echo $row ['username'] ; ?> Profile</h2>   with the session start and db connect at top of the page

Comment: then print out your query: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; echo $sql; die(); Then go to PHPMyAdmin and run it. May be there is no user with this username or something like that

Comment: And put this query here of couse

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to start the session first

```
session_start();
```

Comment: I have put it at the top of the page and the db connect but still nothing i have $username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET ['nicky'] ) ;

$result123 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
   WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());


// get the first (and hopefully only) entry from the result
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result123 );


?>
</p>
<center>
  <h2 align="left"><?php echo $row ['username'] ; ?> Profile</h2>   with the db and session start ont op of it